# How can i specify the architecture in Github Actions?

Tags: github, github-actions, github-actions-runners

How can I specify the architecture (something like `x86` or `arm64`) in Github Actions?

Comment: For what? The runner? The compiler? Your app?

Comment: For the runner.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No you cannot set the architecture for the GitHub hosted runner. These VMs run x64. There is currently no way to specify or request another architecture.

If you need runners on arm64 or x86 you'll need to setup your own host/ VM and install the runner into it along with any other tools your build process needs.

You can use the GitHub/virtual-environments repo to borrow the setup scripts, but you'll need to make the proper adjustments to support the architecture of your choice.

Comment: It looks like there is an [alpha version for supporting arm64](https://blog.travis-ci.com/2019-10-07-multi-cpu-architecture-support) (only on linux os)

Comment: @DavidWer that link points to TravesCI, not GitHub Actions. I don't see ARM on the roadmap for the coming months.

Answer (score 0):

As @jessehouwing said, you will need to use self-hosted runners. GitHub hosted runners don't support arm64 yet. You can create the runner yourself by spinning up an arm64 VM and installing [actions/runner](https://github.com/actions/runner). You can also use a separate more complete solution that would create those runners on the fly. You have three solid options:

- [terraform-aws-github-runner](https://github.com/philips-labs/terraform-aws-github-runner#arm64-support-via-gravitongraviton2-instance-types) has documentation on creating arm64 runners.
- [Kubernetes actions-runner-controller](https://github.com/actions-runner-controller/actions-runner-controller) doesn't have any easily found arm64 support, but I bet it does support it.
- [cdk-github-runners](https://github.com/CloudSnorkel/cdk-github-runners) which is my project so I'm a bit biased towards it. I believe it's the easiest to setup. You can get arm64 runners going with:

```js
import { aws_codebuild as codebuild } from 'aws-cdk-lib';
import { Architecture, CodeBuildRunnerProvider } from '@cloudsnorkel/cdk-github-runners';

new GitHubRunners(this, 'runners', {
  providers: [
    new CodeBuildRunnerProvider(this, 'CodeBuild ARM64', {
      labels: ['codebuild', 'arm64'],
      computeType: codebuild.ComputeType.SMALL,
      imageBuilder: CodeBuildRunnerProvider.imageBuilder(this, 'Runner Image Builder', {
        architecture: Architecture.ARM64,
      }),
    }),
  ],
});
```

Your workflows should then use `runs-on: [self-hosted, codebuild, arm64]`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of qemu and cross-platform docker images to achieve the result.  There is a GH workflow action that attempts to package this up for you called [run-on-architecture](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/run-on-architecture).

You can also package the build actions into a dockerfile, build that dockerfile and (if necessary) copy the output to the host runner.  I'll try to provide a small example:

Dockerfile:

```
FROM debian:bullseye

ENV project myproject
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive
ENV LC_ALL en_US.UTF-8
ENV LANG ${LC_ALL}

RUN echo "#log: ${project}: Setup system" \
  && set -x \
  && apt-get update -y \
  && apt-get install -y \
    build-essential \
    python3 \
  && apt-get clean \
  && sync

ADD . /usr/local/opt/${project}
WORKDIR /usr/local/opt/${project}

RUN echo "#log: ${project}: Running build" \
  && set -x \
  && ./configure \
  && make \
  && make dist

CMD /bin/bash -l
```

This is all vanilla dockerfile so far.  The trick now is to run this on several architectures with the help of quemu-user.  There's a github action that sets this up as well.

For starters, here is how you would run this locally, cross-platform:

```
docker build --name --tag my-builder --platform linux/arm64
docker build --name --tag my-builder --platform linux/arm
```

Then you can copy the artifacts using `docker create` and `docker cp`:

```
CONTAINER=$docker create --platform "linux/arm64" my-builder)
docker cp "$CONTAINER:/usr/local/opt/myproject/*.tar.gz" .
docker rm "$CONTAINER"

CONTAINER=$docker create --platform "linux/arm" my-builder)
docker cp "$CONTAINER:/usr/local/opt/myproject/*.tar.gz" .
docker rm "$CONTAINER"
```

From here, there are a couple ways to run this inside a github action.  One would be to use the [setup-qemu-action](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/docker-setup-qemu). Then run the build and copy steps in your workflow.  Something like this:

```
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-22.04
    strategy:
      matrix:
        platform: [linux/amd64, linux/arm64, linux/arm]
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v4
      - uses: docker/setup-qemu-action@v3
        with:
          image: tonistiigi/binfmt:latest
          platforms: arm,arm64
      - run: >
          docker build .
          --tag my-builder
          --platform ${{ matrix.platform }}
      - run: >
          docker create
          --name node-bcryptjs-builder
          --platform ${{ matrix.platform }}
          my-builder
      - run: docker cp "my-builder:/usr/local/opt/myproject/*.tar.gz .
```

See also:

- https://docs.docker.com/build/building/multi-platform/
- https://nullprogram.com/blog/2021/08/21/
- https://www.stereolabs.com/docs/docker/building-arm-container-on-x86/

Answer (score 0):

If you have Github Teams or Enterprise you can with `runs-on`.

Here is an example and the docs are [here](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-github-hosted-runners/about-larger-runners/about-larger-runners#overview-of-larger-runners)

The only Arm type I see is the `XLarge` arm64 (M1)

```
name: learn-github-actions-testing
on: [push]
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: macos-13-xlarge
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v4
      - name: Build
        run: swift build
      - name: Run tests
        run: swift test
```

Answer (score -1):

I believe you can specify architecture as an environment variable.

```
- name: Set up Python 3.8.5
  uses: actions/setup-python@v3
  with:
    architecture: 'x64'
    python-version: 3.8.5
```